# Inform LINQ that a string represents a decimal and not a double value?

Tags: linq-to-entities

I am using the following snippet:

```
var ws = string.Format(" it.{0} >= {1} && it.{0} <= {2} ", column, min, max)
```

as part of query.
“it” represents the record at hand.
I then use this string in a

```
Var result = AllRecords
        .Where(ws)
        .OrderBy(it.ProductName);
```

The problem I have, is that when the column type is Decimal the LINQ interprets the passed in string as double and fails by saying the types double and decimal are incompatible:

> The argument types 'Edm.Decimal' and
>   'Edm.Double' are incompatible for this
>   operation. Near greater than or equals
>   expression, line 8, column 12. where:
>   (  it.Cost >= 70.5 && it.Cost <= 100 )
>   orderby: it.ProductName

how can I ensure that LINQ will realize the string must be interpreted as decimal and not double?

Answer (score 2):

Found it:
I need to suffix the string that contains a double with 'M', in my case:

```
var ws = string.Format(" it.{0} >= {1} && it.{0} <= {2} ", column, min+'M', max+'M');
```